# tex maker pdf suddently not working

Tags: errors, pdf

I will try to explain what my problem is.

I have written my thesis with tex maker without any problem. However, yesterday I open it to correct a couple of things. I corrected them without problems. So every file.tex with the chapters seem to be fine. But I went to compile the pdf and I got the following message: error: file not found. I have not touch or change anything. So I don't really know what has happened.

I am just about to submit my thesis. So any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. I believe it may be a little or silly thing but I can't fine where the problem is. I attached 2 screenshots, one with the error and another one with the the configuration of the screen of tex maker with my thesis.tex file, in case it is useful.

If you need a minimun example of my thesis.tex, let me know exactly what you need and I will upload it.

scren of my tex maker[image: image of my thesis.tex with which I normally compile the pdf and the message of error]

Comment: at first ensure that you have backup of your files. Then go to the main file and put \end{document} near \begin{document} so that you have only a short document. Try if that compiles.

Comment: Should I just leave \begin document with the front matter and the title page and \end document and see if pdf LaTex compile the title page and list of figures. What do you think @Ulrike?

Comment: simply start with something short, so that you know if texmaker compiles your document at all.

Comment: I see in the screenshot that your files are in a remote folder, or in a folder that is synced to the cloud. Once you have a copy of your files safely somewhere else, retry compiling from a normal, local folder.

Comment: @Miyase, I will try it this afternoon. It may work. However, It has been working properly in its current synced folder for 4 years. But who knows, it could work :)

Comment: Don't forget that using a sync folder puts you at the mercy of the company handling the sync procotol. They can make changes that affect you without any way for you to control it. With some sync services in the past, I did have problems with LaTeX files (but not OneDrive, which I've never used).

Comment: also why use latex/dvips/pstopdf rather than pdflatex, and why specify `ansinew` as a non standard file encoding rather than utf-8, and then re-set to utf-8 a few lines later?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I have deleted imputenc. I will only use utf8. By the way, I have sorted out the mystery of the missing pdf. I have thoroughly checked out my thesis.log file and have found that yesterday I moved a figure in one of the chapters and added by mistake an extra "{" to the caption of the figure. In addition, I have made other arrangements in my preamble, like deleting begin and end flushright before documentclass and so on and so forth. Thanks for your help folks.

Comment: I just noticed your editor menu is showing pdflatex, so you are using pdflatex not latex in which case `[dvips]` option to `graphicx` is completly wrong and will prevent it working.

Comment: Many thanks. I will replace \usepackage dvips option to graphicx for \usepackage{graphicx}